# When should an Actor be created in the Actor System vs Actor Context?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

In Akka when should I create an Actor using `system.actorOf()` vs `context.actorOf()`?

I know `context.actorOf()` creates a child actor, but when should one actor be a child of another vs top level?

Answer (score 1):

you should avoid creating actors under the System actor. It's usually a good strategy to have new Actors as Children of your own (context) actor and group them accordingly and hierarchically.

That way you have better granularity to control the life cycle of your Actors, which implies you can control how many instances of each type of actor you need at any time (dynamically).

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/actors.html

http://getakka.net/docs/Actor%20lifecycle

Comment: Is there any circumstance where I would want to create the actor under the System actor? For example, if I had a `FileWriterActor`, a `LogActor`, and a `ReceiptActor` that both needed to write to a file, should `FileWriterActor` be a child of both `LogActor` and `ReceiptActor`?

Comment: Not sure about the structure there, but it seems to me that you should pass either the FileWriteActor or it's manager(preferable) ref to the LogActor and also to the ReceiptActor. So they can send messages to the FileWriteActor. By having a parent Actor, you would be able to switch to different FileWriter w/o needing to update the actor ref on any other Actor.